# Minimum value of $xy(72-3x-4y)$ for $x,y>0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

QUESTION -**If x,y>0  then what can be the minimum value of the product 
xy(72-3x-4y)**
at the first look i tried to manipulate the question.and then by minimising the given expression using AM - GM inequality but it did not work . So how to manipulate the above expression to get the answer.

Comment: Possibly the second partial derivative test?

Comment: Are there any other restrictions? Because the answer will be $-\infty$ presently.

Comment: Perhaps you meant maximum, not minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant maximum, not minimum, just find critical points of the function
$$f(x,y) = xy(72-3x - 4y)$$
in the triangular region of the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane, bounded by the axes and the line $3x + 4y = 72$.

Since $f$ is continuous, positive inside the triangle, and zero on the boundary, $f$ has an absolute maximum inside the triangle, which must occur at a critical point.

Taking partial derivatives, setting them to zero, and solving for $x,y,\;$you'll find there is exactly one critical point inside the triangle, namely the point $(8,6)$.

It follows that the desired maximum value is $f(8,6)=1152$.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use AM/GM to get the **maximum** notice that
$$f(x,y)=\frac{(3x)(4y)(72-3x-4y)}{12}=\frac{uvw}{12}$$
where $u=3x$, $v=4y$ and $u+v+w=72$. We are given $u$, $v>0$
and as we only are interested in the maximum, then we may assume $w>0$.
By AM/GM
$$f(x,y)\le\frac1{12}\left(\frac{u+v+w}3\right)^3=\frac{24^3}{12}$$
etc. with maximum where $u=v=w=24$ so $x=8$, $y=6$.